# (Nowhere) density of a space of natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

A set in a metric space can't be both dense and nowhere dense. Take space $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers endowed with a usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. Take subset of the space equal to itself, *i.e.* all natural numbers. That set is dense in itself, and is nowhere dense since it doesn't contain any open intervals and thus has empty interior, so how can it be both dense and nowhere dense? I think I am misunderstanding what open sets are (how they can differ depending on the topology) or I am not completely catching the definition of (nowhere) density.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please edit and explain precisely what your question is.

Comment: The question is clear to me @DavidRaveh

Comment: Every set is open in the space $\mathbb N$ endowed with the Euclidean metric. Indeed, taking $r=1$, $B_r(x)\subset E$ if $x\in E$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang are you saying interval like (3,5) (ball around 4) belongs to the space of natural numbers?

Comment: $(3,5)\cap \mathbb N = \{4\}$

Comment: A ball of any radius around a point 4 will not be contained in the space of naturals I thought?

Comment: If $\mathbb N$ is the metric space, other points do not exist.

Comment: @AndrewZhang got it. So we need to look at the intersection then to determine containment?

Comment: “So we need to look at the intersection,” No, you shouldn’t invent points which are not there. If you want to talk about relative open, then yes. But if you are merely talking about whether a set is open, as is the case here, then those other points do not exist, and so intersections is the wrong way to think about it.

Comment: @AndrewZhang I think this made it clear for me, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The concepts of density and nowhere-density apply only to subsets. The key question is subsets of *which* space?

As you know, given a metric space* $(X, d)$, and a subset $A \subseteq X$, we say that $A$ is a *dense subset* of $X$, or that $A$ is dense in $X$, if the closure of $A$ in $X$ is the entire space: $\bar{A} = X$.

We say that $A$ is *nowhere-dense* in $X$ if the interior of the closure of $A$ in $X$ is empty: $\mathop{\mathrm{int}} \bar{A} = \varnothing$.

An important takeaway of the definition of a dense subset is that **every set is dense in itself**. For any space $(X, d)$ equipped with any metric $d$, we have $X \subseteq X$ is a dense subset.

Somewhat less importantly, the empty set is a nowhere-dense subset of any set.

This means that a subset of a metric space *can* be both dense and nowhere-dense. . . Given that it's the subset $\varnothing$ of the metric space $(\varnothing, \varnothing)$.

This is how we have the following two facts simultaneously:

1. The natural numbers are a nowhere-dense subset $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ of the space of the real numbers under the standard metric $(\mathbb{R}, d_\mathrm{std})$.
2. The natural numbers are a dense subset $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ of the space of the natural numbers under *any* metric $(\mathbb{N}, d)$. (And hence, under the subspace metric $(\mathbb{N}, d_\mathrm{std}\rvert_\mathbb{N})$ inherited from $(\mathbb{R}, d_\mathrm{std})$.)

A Ti*k*Z illustration which will hopefully be of some assistance follows:

[image: Illustration]

<sub>*We use metric spaces throughout this question, though the concept generalizes to arbitrary topological spaces.</sub>

Comment: Yes, I figured I didn't consider the space the density and nowhere density of the set were considered to be inside of properly. I just didn't look at it in the right way i.e. if we consider space of naturals then points R \ N don't exist,  and I also didn't understand what an open set was considered to be in case of such a space. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have most of the right idea, but it's clear that you haven't considered what the "open balls" look like in the metric space you've described.

Given any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and any real $r>0,$ the open ball centered at $n$ with radius $r$ has the form $$\{m\in\Bbb N:\lvert m-n\rvert<r\}$$ by definition, and so has following (equivalent) forms: $$\bigl\{m\in\mathbb{N}:-r<m-n<r\bigr\}\\\bigl\{m\in\mathbb{N}:n-r<m<n+r\bigr\}\\\bigl\{m\in\mathbb{N}:\lfloor n-r\rfloor<m<\lceil n+r\rceil\bigr\}\\\bigl\{m\in\mathbb{N}:\lfloor n-r\rfloor+1\leq m\leq\lceil n+r\rceil-1\bigr\}\\\bigl\{m\in\mathbb{N}:\min(0,\lfloor n-r\rfloor)+1\leq m\leq\lceil n+r\rceil-1\bigr\}.$$ That last assumes that $1$ is the least element of $\mathbb{N}.$ If your version of $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0,$ it should instead say $\min(-1,\lfloor n-r\rfloor).$

Either way, think about what this could look like for various values of $n$ and $r.$ You should quickly discover that in particular, for each $n\in\mathbb{N},$ the set $\{n\}$ is an open ball, so the only subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with empty interior is the empty set!

Comment: Exactly! Thank you. I just didn't quite catch the notion that points corresponding to non-natural numbers simply do not exist in the space of natural numbers.